# My Copy Directory Functions Fails Occasionally

Tags: c#, directory, copy

I'm having problems with the code below occasionally failing to complete due to not releasing a file that its copying. I would like to wrap this function in a using statement, but not sure how to do this or if there was a better solution than this.

Thanks.

```
public static void CopyDirectory (string source, string destination)
{
  if (!Directory.Exists (destination))
    Directory.CreateDirectory (destination);

  string [] sysEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (source);

  foreach (string sysEntry in sysEntries)
  {
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName (sysEntry);
    string targetPath = Path.Combine (destination, fileName);

    if (Directory.Exists (sysEntry))
      CopyDirectory (sysEntry, targetPath);

    else
      File.Copy (sysEntry, targetPath, true);
  } // foreach (string sysEntry in sysEntries)
}
```

Comment: How do you know your program is failing due to not releasing a file that it is copying? Does it throw any exception? or does it just block and never finish?

Comment: Hi kaptan. The application that uses this code watches a folder and then copies that folder to another server on a network. An empty folder is created at the destination, but no files are copied to it. Most of the time the application works and I can't figure out why it fails sometimes.

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the directories it is failing to copy? You need at least read permission for the user running the program.

Comment: BTW, I would use Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries instead of Directory.GetFileSystemEntries in case you hit a directory with too many entries that may potentially slow down your program.